# My selector options are undefined but the selector length is good

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, twig

I send to my twig page an array composed of 3 objects (my unit tests are valid, my objects are not null here):

```php
echo $this->twig->render('form/index.html.twig', ['verbalAggressions' => $verbal_aggressions]);
```

Then I get :

```js
const verbalAggressions = {{ verbalAggressions|json_encode }};
```

My variable is composed of 3 objects, but they are undefined :

[image]

I use version 3.4.3 of twig, maybe I should upgrade?

My properties of model :

```php
<?php

namespace app\models;

use app\database\Database;

/**
 * The aggressions
 */
class Aggression
{
    /**
     * @var int
     */
    private int $id;
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private string $name;
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private string $type;

    /**
     * @param int $id
     * @param string $name
     * @param string $type
     */
    public function __construct(int $id, string $name, string $type)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->type = $type;
    }
```

My getters :

```php
 public function getId(): int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName(): string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getType(): string
    {
        return $this->type;
    }
```

My method to get verbal aggressions :

```php
public static function getVerbalAggressions(): array|null
    {
        $aggressions = Aggression::findAll();
        if ($aggressions != null) {
            $verbalAggressions = [];
            foreach ($aggressions as $verbalAggression) {
                if ($verbalAggression instanceof Aggression) {
                    if ($verbalAggression->getType() == 'Verbale' || $verbalAggression->getType() == 'Commun') {
                        $verbalAggressions[] = $verbalAggression;
                    }
                }
            }
            return $verbalAggressions;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us what those objects look like in PHP? Are the properties you expect possibly protected/private? By default, only public properties will be used when you json encode objects.

Comment: I added my model with my method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The properties in your object are private, which means that they will be ignored when you json encode the object.

If you want to keep those properties private, you can use the [JsonSerializable-interface](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.jsonserializable.php) to decide what you want the object to use when it's being serialized as json.

1. Let `Aggression` implement the interface:

```php
use JsonSerializable;

class Aggression implements JsonSerializable
{
```

2. Add the required method to the class:

```php
/**
 * Return the data that should be json serialized
 * 
 * @return mixed
 */
public function jsonSerialize(): mixed
{
    // Here you can return an array with all the properties you want in your json
    return [
        'id' => $this->getId(),
        'name' => $this->getName(),
        'type' => $this->getType(),
    ];
}
```

If you now pass the object to `json_encode()`, PHP will use the response of the objects `jsonSerialize()`-method.

Demo: https://3v4l.org/KueIs

Comment: Thanks you very much ! 

I added raw filter to make it work 

const verbalAggressions = {{ verbalAggressions | json_encode | raw }};